# Statically configured NIC's loose all settings when I turn Azure machines back on

Tags: azure

I configured two AD controllers and a WINS server in Azure each with static IP's and then turned them off for the weekend.  Now that I turn the machines back on, all of the NIC's are setup to obtain an IP automatically.

When I go back into the NIC and reconfigure it for a static IP, I get an error message that the IP address I entered for the network adapter is already assigned to another adopter which is no longer present in the computer.  Then it asks me if I want to remove the static IP configuration for the absent adapter.

What is happening here?  Is there something I am configuring incorrectly that forces my configured static NIC's to change?  Do I want to answer yes and reconfigure the card yet again, or is there a better way to go about this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer my own question just in case someone is doing a network search looking for an answer and winds up here.

The issue centers on, for me at least, the differences between what is required for setting up bare metal AD environments as opposed to AD environments in Azure.  In bare metal we are used to configuring inside of the NIC.  In Azure, you work in two places.  You create your AD's with DNS and then you use the Azure powershell to configure the AD controller's static IP and then you go back to your virtual network and register the DNS servers that were created.

There are some things happening behind the scenes in Azure that make this work.  So, just create your AD's with DNS.  Get the IP that was assigned by DHCP and register it with the Azure powershell and then list the name of the AD and it's IP in the virtual network and you are done.

Hope this helps.